# Python: extracting numbers from a txt file and writing to the file using try statement

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, try-except

Ok, I'm trying to use a `Try` statement to see if a file can be opened. If it can verify if the number is less than the user's score, and if it is, write the new high score.

the `Else` part covers that if the file does not exist, write a new one with a high score.

However, nothing seems to work. It either writes the high score twice or regardless whether the score is lower or higher.

```
try:
    highscore = open('highscore.txt', 'r')
    score_line = highscore.readlines()
    read_score = re.findall(r"\d+", str(score_line))
    score = [int(num) for num in read_score]
    highscore.close()

    if score[0] < total_points:
        highscore = open('highscore.txt', 'a')

        highscore.write('\nScore: ' + str(total_points)
                        + '\nName: ' + name
                        + '\n')
        print('Your highscore has been saved!')
        highscore.close()
    else:
        pass
except OSError:
    pass
else:
    highscore = open('highscore.txt', 'a')

    highscore.write('\nScore: ' + str(total_points)
                    + '\nName: ' + name
                    + '\n')
    highscore.close()

    print('Your highscore has been saved!')
```

Comment: The else branch is executed if no OSError was raised. So it will only be run if the file exists, and appends to it. The behavior you see is exactly what the code describes.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of 'try except else' you can use simple if. 
This code writes the highscore in the highscore.txt file.
If the file doesn't exist this code will create a file and write the current score as high score.

```
    import os
    import re
    txt_file = 'highscore.txt'# if the txt file is not in the same folder then provide the full path
    score = 50 #current score
    name= 'Sachin'
    data = f'''Name: {name}
    Score: {score}
    '''

    # if the text file doesn't exists write the current score as high score
    if not os.path.exists(txt_file):
        with open(txt_file,'w') as f:
            f.write(f'{data}')

    #read the score
    with open(txt_file,'r') as f:
        previous_score = f.read()
        previous_score = re.search('\d+',previous_score).group(0)

    # compare the previous score with current score and write the highest score with name
    if int(previous_score) < int(score):
        with open(txt_file,'w') as f:
            f.write(f'{data}')
```

Comment: This works, but the problem is I need to add ```Name : ___``` and ```Score: ___```. If I put those in there I get a ValueError.

Answer (score 0):

Let's address several things one by one:

- Question: Create a minimal example
- Answer: Why your try/else doesn't work
- Best practice: Make the try/except as tight as possible
- Best practice: Use 'with'

### Minimal

We don't really need the details for the try/except part:

```
try:
    highscore = open('highscore.txt', 'r')
    print highscore.read()
    highscore.close()
except OSError:
    pass
else:
    highscore = open('highscore.txt', 'a')
    highscore.write('foo')
    highscore.close()
```

### Question

Why doesn't it work?  The try / except / else hits the else when there is *no exception*, and the *except* when there is an exception.  You want your code in the *except* part, and therefore don't even need an else.

```
try:
    highscore = open('highscore.txt', 'r')
    print highscore.read()
    highscore.close()
except OSError:
    highscore = open('highscore.txt', 'a')
    highscore.write('foo')
    highscore.close()
```

### Tighten try/except

You won't hit an OSError with (e.g.: `re.findall`), so lets make it as small as possible.

### Use with

Then you don't need to close the file yourself either.

### Use json/yaml to store data

Avoids regex parsing and lots of string details, use other code to chose the output format.

### Use 'w' instead of 'a' if you are just overwriting the file anyways

### Final suggested version

```
PATH = 'highscore.json'
try:
    with open(PATH, 'r') as f:
        info = json.load(f)
except (OSError, json.JSONDecodeError):
    info = {}
score = info.get('score')
if score is None or score < total_points:
    with open(PATH, 'w') as f:
        json.dump({'name': name, 'score': total_points}, f)
    print('Your highscore has been saved!')
```

Comment: this gives me an error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  line 190, in main
    info = json.load(f)
line 293, in load
    return loads(fp.read(),
line 357, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Comment: Your file might not be proper json (perhaps you copied the text file there?) I added an `except json.JSONDecodeError` to handle your specific case, but it's hard to tell without more context